# static image doesn't show in checkout page magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, image-preview

I was override `Magento_Checkout/shipping-address/shipping-method-item` static html file with `Vendor_Module/checkout/shipping/shipping-method-item` static html file.

now I wants to set static image URL in this `shipping-method-item` file. So, I put that static image at `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/images/location.png`.

then I mention code as like below in `shipping-method-item` file

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: require.toUrl('Vendor_Module::images/location.png') }" alt="">
```

but it doesn't generate any path for image.

even I tried as like below

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: require.toUrl('images/location.png') }" alt="">
```

then it generate path as like below

domain.com/static/version1663150096/frontend/Vendor_Name/Theme_Name/en_US/images/location.png

I doesn't have any idea about how to show image from my custom module path `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/images/location.png`

please help me...

---

**Answer :-**

Step 1 :- put image at `/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/images/location.png` location path

Step 2 :- write img tag code as like below in your static html file

```
<img data-bind="attr: { src: require.toUrl('Vendor_Module/images/location.png') }" alt="location-icon">
```

Anwser Given By:- @Bharath Kumar [see here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/359946/93504)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to produce an image from the static files generated please follow the below sol:-

I have tried in my local development environment and have found a solution , the issue is with the image path actually , please check this browser screenshot as a proof that image can be shown

[image]

In your HTML file , you should call the image something like this:-

```
<img data-bind="attr:{src:require.toUrl('OX_PrintSampleContent/images/images.jpeg')}">
```

Please check this screenshot of the HTML code

[image]

This is the path where you should place your image in your module

app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/web/images/images.jpeg

If this post has helped , please do like this helps me motivate me more to post such answers.Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks you for helping me. now It's works.

Comment: Very Glad , have a nice day.

Comment: I need to complete the order without shipment createing for storepickup order type. I doesn't have any idea about how to achive this. can you help me for achive this problem? I need to achive this one from Magento Admin side & API also @Bharath Kumar J